# Whoop API Error when trying to login with passport and OAuth 2.0

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, oauth-2.0, passport.js

Hi I'm trying to make a log in using whoop api, currently they use passport and OAuth2.0, but it seems that it gaves me an error when i do the passport.authenticate in the callback endpoint.
This is my User.js routes

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const passport = require('passport')
const OAuth2Strategy = require('passport-oauth2')
const User = require('../Models/User')
require('dotenv').config()

const whoopOAuthConfig = {
    authorizationURL: `${process.env.WHOOP_API_HOSTNAME}/oauth/oauth2/auth`,
    tokenURL: `${process.env.WHOOP_API_HOSTNAME}/oauth/oauth2/token`,
    clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: process.env.CALLBACK_URL,
    state: true,
    scope: [
        'offline',
        'read:profile',
        'read:recovery',
        'read:cycles',
        'read:sleep',
        'read:workout',
        'read:body_measurement'
    ],
}

async function  getUser(
    accessToken,
    refreshToken,
    {expires_in},
    profile,
    done,
){
    console.log(profile)
    const {first_name, last_name, user_id} = profile

    const user = await User.findOne({userId: user_id})

    if (user) {
        user.acessToken = accessToken
        user.refreshToken = refreshToken
        user.expiresIn = Date.now() + expires_in * 1000
        user.firstName = first_name
        user.lastName = last_name
        user.userId = user_id

        await user.save()

        done(err, user)
    } else{
        const newUser = new User({
            acessToken: accessToken,
            refreshToken: refreshToken,
            expiresIn: Date.now() + expires_in * 1000,
            firstName: first_name,
            lastName: last_name,
            userId: user_id,
        })

        done(err, newUser)
    }
}

async function fetchProfile(
    accessToken,
    done,
){
    console.log(accessToken)
    const profileResponse = await fetch(
        `${process.env.WHOOP_API_HOSTNAME}/developer/v1/user/profile/basic`,
        {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
            },
        },
    )

    const profile = await profileResponse.json()

    done(err, profile)
}

const whoopAuthorizationStrategy = new OAuth2Strategy(whoopOAuthConfig, getUser)
whoopAuthorizationStrategy.userProfile = fetchProfile

passport.use('oauth2', whoopAuthorizationStrategy)

var printSometing = function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("I'm still here");
    return next();
}

app.get('/auth/performance',
    passport.authenticate('oauth2'));



app.get('/auth/performance/callback',
    passport.authenticate('oauth2', {failureRedirect: '/', failureMessage: true }),
printSometing, function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/');
});



module.exports = app;
```

And this is my index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 8081
const cors = require('cors')
const session = require('express-session')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
require('dotenv').config()
var bodyParser = require( 'body-parser' );
const passport = require('passport')


mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI)
const database = mongoose.connection;

database.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

database.once('connected', function() {
  console.log("Connected to MongoDB")
});


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send({msg: 'Hello World!'})
})

app.use(session({secret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET, resave: true, saveUninitialized: true}))
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '10mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: '10mb' }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(cors());

app.use('/api', require('./routes/user.js'));

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

I've followed the Whoop's API documentation and it didn't work, tried to change the secret and api keys and online reasearch.

Answer (score 0):

Before you add the complexity of a specific API (such as Passport), it might be helpful to experiment with authenticating using rocks and sticks. I mean, of course, using a browser and "curl", a command-line tool.

OAuth2 is built on HTTPS 'GET' and 'PUT', which is actually surprisingly simple: (1) One "GET" in a browser to get Whoop to ask for a username & password, and (2) One "PUT" from curl to ask Whoop to give you the access token.

Here's a link that shows how to do this pretty clearly: https://backstage.forgerock.com/knowledge/kb/article/a45882528 ("How do I perform common OAuth 2.0 tasks using curl commands...")

I also found it helpful to read the OAuth2.0 spec, which you can find here: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749. (I said "helpful", but not necessarily painless! :-)